# Strange characters in HTTP-request

Tags: ios, http, character-encoding

Hi i am trying to copy a webrequest that is sent from a webpage to an app on iOS as an exercise. Problem is that when the webpage sends a POST containing among other the text lang=C++ it encodes the text to lang=C%2B%2B Further more, the data sent seems corrupt, am I missing some kind of coding? Im sending the requests using an `NSMutableString` data with the setBody encoding message : `NSUTF8StringEncoding`, see code below:

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    ...(URL and so on)...
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[data  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Refer to these screenshots from wireshark for more information about the different styles of the requests sent by the app vs. the webservice, the highlighted text in the bottom image is what i want to send. The top image shows what is actually sent by the app, as it is now.

[image: what i seem to be posting]

[image: What should be posted]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above answer did not work for me, i had to make a category extending the `NSString` interface according to [this](http://madebymany.com/blog/url-encoding-an-nsstring-on-ios). And use the encoding on certain parts of the `data` string above.

Here's the method of the category that I used:

```
#import "NSString+URLEncoding.h"
@implementation NSString (URLEncoding)
-(NSString *)urlEncodeUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding {
    return (__bridge NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                                               (CFStringRef)self,
                                                               NULL,
                                                               (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ",
                                                               CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use NSString's `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` method in order to encode the URL and the opposite would be to decode using `stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`

This encoding should be done before the string is serialized to `NSData` of course

Comment: It almost worked, but i ended upp writing an encoder in a NSString category. Thank you